# How can I receive unclaimed Uplay points?

Tags: ubisoft-connect

Uplay shows that I have got unclaimed Uplay points, most likely from the time I played the assassin's creed series on the PS3, I do not have access to the console anymore. How can I claim the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to https://account.ubisoft.com/en-GB/login
2. Log in using the account use in Uplay;
3. scroll to the bottom until you reach "linked accounts" section;
4. click on "link PSN account" and follow the instructions.

Once you're done with this, it should automatically grant you the Uplay points.

After that, UPlay points can be redeemed in the Uplay client for ingame benefits for any uPlay title.